# Expected ";" before Object_name C++

Tags: c++, oop, bgi

I have two files. One a header file named shape.h. I wanted to call the shapes from the class through the header file. But the file is not compiling.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <graphics.h>
using namespace std;

class Shape{
    protected:
        int x;
        int y;
    public:
        Shape(){
            x =0;
            y = 0;
            int gd = DETECT, gm;
            char pathtodriver[] = "";
            initgraph(&gd, &gm, pathtodriver);
        }
        virtual void draw();
};

class Rectangle : public Shape{
    protected:
        int x1;
        int y1;

    public:

        Rectangle(int x, int y,int x1,int y1){
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
            this->x1 = x1;
            this->y1 = y1;
        };

        void draw(){
            rectangle(200,200,100,250);
            closegraph();
        };
};


class Circle : public Shape{
    protected:
        int x1;

    public:

        Circle(int x,int y,int x1){
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
            this->x1 = x1;
        };
        void draw(){
            circle(x,y,x1);
            closegraph();
        };
};

class Ellipse : public Shape{
    protected:
        int a;
        int b;
        int x1;
        int y1;

    public:

        Ellipse(int x,int y,int a, int b,int x1,int y1){
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
            this->a = a;
            this->b = b;
            this->x1 = x1;
            this->y1 = y1;
        };
        void draw(){
            ellipse(x,y,a,b,x1,y1);
            closegraph();
        };
};
```

And another file to call in shapes.

```
#include "shape.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Shape *s1;
    cout<<"1.Rectangle"<<
    "2.Circle"<<
    "3.Ellipse"<<
    "4.Exit"<<endl;
    int choice;
    cout<<"Enter your choice :"<<endl;
    cin >> choice;
    switch(choice){
    case 1:
        Rectangle R1(100,100,50,60);
        s1 = &R1;
        s1->draw();
        break;

    case 2:
        Circle c1(100,100,20);
        s1 = &c1;
        s1 ->draw();
        break;

    case 3:
        Ellipse e1(100,100,0,360,30,40);
        s1 = &e1;
        s1->draw();
        break;

    case 4:
        exit(0);

    default:
        cout<<"Error choice";
    }

}
```

But it gives the following errors:

```
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
C:\Users\rbmoh\OneDrive\Desktop\Docs\C++\shape.h||In constructor 'Shape::Shape()':|
C:\Users\rbmoh\OneDrive\Desktop\Docs\C++\shape.h|14|warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]|
C:\Users\rbmoh\OneDrive\Desktop\Docs\C++\labb7.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\rbmoh\OneDrive\Desktop\Docs\C++\labb7.cpp|13|error: expected ';' before 'R1'|
C:\Users\rbmoh\OneDrive\Desktop\Docs\C++\labb7.cpp|14|error: 'R1' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\rbmoh\OneDrive\Desktop\Docs\C++\labb7.cpp|20|error: jump to case label [-fpermissive]|
C:\Users\rbmoh\OneDrive\Desktop\Docs\C++\labb7.cpp|17|note:   crosses initialization of 'Circle c1'|
C:\Users\rbmoh\OneDrive\Desktop\Docs\C++\labb7.cpp|21|error: expected ';' before 'e1'|
C:\Users\rbmoh\OneDrive\Desktop\Docs\C++\labb7.cpp|22|error: 'e1' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\rbmoh\OneDrive\Desktop\Docs\C++\labb7.cpp|24|error: jump to case label [-fpermissive]|
C:\Users\rbmoh\OneDrive\Desktop\Docs\C++\labb7.cpp|17|note:   crosses initialization of 'Circle c1'|
C:\Users\rbmoh\OneDrive\Desktop\Docs\C++\labb7.cpp|27|error: jump to case label [-fpermissive]|
C:\Users\rbmoh\OneDrive\Desktop\Docs\C++\labb7.cpp|17|note:   crosses initialization of 'Circle c1'|
||=== Build failed: 7 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Please help

I tried changing the name of class but it did not work as well. The code did not compile.

Comment: Please include the errors as text in the question and indicate where in the above code they refer to.

Comment: There's quite a lot wrong with this code, but I'm struggling to see how it causes the errors mentioned.

Comment: You need to put the `case`s statements in `{` ... `} break;`  blocks. You also need to initialize `choice`.

Comment: The break statement does not affect the compiling of the code

Comment: protected data is almost always a bad idea

Comment: The first error is about (stone age) `initgraph` taking a `char*` parameter, but a string literal decays to a `const char*`. So no match. Most of the rest then follows from Shape not compiling properly.

Comment: You do realize the `s1` variable is kind of useless? The specific shapes go out of scope when the `switch` is done, so `s1` becomes a dangling pointer at that time making any dereferencing Undefined Behaviour. You could simply use e.g. `c1.draw()`.

Comment: Yes I realize that. This is my class assignment, which specified to use a pointer. But even though I remove the s1 pointer, it will still not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to but the `case` statements with declarations in `{` ... `}` blocks. You also need to add `break`s to not fallthrough to the next `case` statement.
You also need to take the `choice` input from the user. You currently use `choice` uninitialized.

Example:

```cpp
while (std::cin >> choice) {
    switch (choice) {
        case 1: {
            Rectangle R1(100, 100, 50, 60);
            s1 = &R1;
            s1->draw();
        } break;

        case 2: {
            Circle c1(100, 100, 20);
            s1 = &c1;
            s1->draw();
        } break;

        case 3: {
            Ellipse e1(100, 100, 0, 360, 30, 40);
            s1 = &e1;
            s1->draw();
        } break;

        case 4:
            std::exit(0);

        default:
            cout << "Error choice";
    }
}
```

Also note that `void initgraph(int *graphdriver, int *graphmode, char *pathtodriver);` takes a `char*` as the last argument. You provide a `const char*`. You need to change that:

```
char pathtodriver[] = "";
initgraph(&gd, &gm, pathtodriver);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6hrxM5avv)